# Explanation in a step of proving the positive semidefinite property of the graph Laplacian

Tags: graph-theory, graph-laplacian

[image]

Here, $W$ is the adjacency matrix, $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $D_{ii} = \sum_{j \neq i} w_{ij} $. I'm not so sure of the second step from the last line. In particular, I can't see how

$$\sum_{i<j} w_{ij} u_i^2 = \sum_{i<j} w_{ij}u_j^2$$

I've tried drawing the summations for visualisation of the double sums, but it doesn't seem to help. Can someone provide a proof of why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Visual hint:** consider the way the integration limits of a double integral change when swapping the order of integration: $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y) \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx = \int_0^1 \int_y^1 f(x,y) \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy.  \tag{*}$$

I would use double sums for clarity:\begin{align}
\sum_i \Bigl(\sum_{j \neq i} w_{ij} \Bigr) u_i^2 &= \sum_i \Bigl(\sum_{j<i} +\sum_{j>i} \Bigr) w_{ij} u_i^2 \\
    &= \sum_i \sum_{j<i} w_{ij} u_i^2   +\sum_i \sum_{j>i} w_{ij} u_i^2 .
\end{align}

For the first sum: rewrite it so that $j$ is the outermost index (*); then, swap the “$i$” and “$j$” labels (they are dummy variables); lastly, recall that $W$ is symmetric ($w_{ji} = w_{ij}$).
\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum_{j<i} w_{ij} u_i^2 &= \sum_j \sum_{i>j} w_{ij} u_i^2 \\
    &= \sum_i \sum_{j>i} w_{ji} u_j^2 \\
    &= \sum_i \sum_{j>i} w_{ij} u_j^2.
\end{align}

Now the two sums have the same structure:
$$\sum_i \Bigl(\sum_{j \neq i} w_{ij} \Bigr) u_i^2 = \sum_i \sum_{j>i} w_{ij} (u_i^2 +u_j^2).$$

Comment: So essentially there is an error in the "proof" that was provided? By this I mean the previous step where $\sum_{i\neq j}$ gets replaced by $2\sum_{i <j}$ - it shouldn't be equal? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no error; notation is just confusing and everyone takes that step for granted. Consider for example a finite function $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$, then this double sum can be computed over just half the domain: $$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} \ \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} f(i,j) = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} f(k,k)  +\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} \ \sum_{i < j \leq n} \bigl(f(i,j)+f(j,i)\bigr) .$$ Then, let $f(i,j) := w_{ij} u_i^2$, for which $w_{ji} = w_{ij}$ and $w_{kk} = 0$, so that the result for $\|u\|_G^2$ follows.